# Reading the below text from one file and write it to another file

Tags: python

I have the below text file where i want to extract new object id value from line 1 and line2:

```
New Record Added, Row 1, Key=comp1, new object id=512684

New Record Added, Row 2, Key=comp2, new object id=512685

Added successfully, job done
```

then extract the values in another text file as below:

```
512684
512685
```

this is what I have tried:

```
f1 = open('input.txt','r')
for i in f1.read().split(','):
    print i
```

It is printing every word separated by comma separately ,now i want to extract all the values with new object id i.e 512684 and 512685

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: I'd recommend you write some code, seems like that would do the trick.

Comment: The error should give you a clue - what is `ffile` in your code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input text is in a file named 'below.txt', this should get the `object_id` values:

```
with open('below.txt') as text_file:
    for line in text_file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if 'new object id' in line:
            object_id = line.split('=')[2]
            print object_id
```

**Output**

```
512684
512685
```

Comment: I just wanted to know what is the use of [2]?

Comment: Add `print line.split('=')` before that line. Or download [PyCharm Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) and use the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a small list of tasks you can break this task into:
(1) import file
(2) loop through for each line
(3) extract the numbers using regex

If you don't know regex, have a look through the tutorials online. I really like this one: https://regexone.com/

Good luck!